# REDIS Consuming 20GB of RAM fo 150k keys

Tags: laravel, redis

I'm using out of the box Laravel's REDIS implementation. I'm caching collections of queries that are needed for the site only, so I get lots of keys that have heavy serialized objects stored in a key as a String Type.

With this, REDIS consumes between 22GB - 25GB(Max memory). This leads sometimes to key evictions which we want to avoid at all costs

Should this be addressed from code POV by optimization (only storing query resultset) or is there something that we're doing wrong on REDIS?

```
used_memory:25182306344
used_memory_human:23.45G
used_memory_rss:24106418176
used_memory_rss_human:22.45G
used_memory_peak:25238402912
used_memory_peak_human:23.51G
used_memory_peak_perc:99.78%
used_memory_overhead:14926818
used_memory_startup:508096
used_memory_dataset:25167379526
used_memory_dataset_perc:99.94%
total_system_memory:32899166208
total_system_memory_human:30.64G
used_memory_lua:37888
used_memory_lua_human:37.00K
maxmemory:26843545600
maxmemory_human:25.00G
maxmemory_policy:allkeys-lru
mem_fragmentation_ratio:0.96
mem_allocator:jemalloc-4.0.3
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0
```

Comment: Your serialized queries are the cache keys? Why not use a hash of the query as key (if it is shorter)?

Comment: No. The resultset, not the query itself. Basically eloquent collections. Edited

Comment: Okay, then the issue is most likely not your code but the resources of redis... or the parameters of your cache (like TTL). As your application seems to make very heavy use of query caching, it might be worth investing some time into figuring out if you can determine whether it is worth caching a query or not (i.e. if a cached query is read from the cache afterwards or not). To me it seems that you either should avoid caching queries where it isn't useful, increase TTL on cache-hit or you stack up your server resources. Or you improve on the serialization (e.g. with ext-igbinary).